# What's the difference between zookeeper vs spring cloud config server?

Tags: spring, cloud, config, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud

What's the difference between zookeeper vs spring cloud config server? They both store configurations in server and make them available to clients.

When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What's the difference between zookeeper vs spring cloud config server?

With the Spring Cloud Config Server you have a central place to manage external properties for applications across all environments. The concepts on config server map identically to the Spring `Environment` and `PropertySource` abstractions, **so they fit very well with Spring applications**, *but can be used with any application running in any language*.

Zookeeper is more than just a Distributed Configuration Server, it's a centralized service  used    for an  almost
bewildering array   of  use cases,  including   configuration   management, synchronizing   data
between services,   leader  election,   message queues, and     as  a   naming
service.

If you want to focus on just the configuration management part, i should say, they're different implementations of the same concept.

With Spring Cloud Config Server, you have a config server backed by a (by default) git repository. Every time a new push happens to that git repository, the config server would be aware of the new configuration values. Clients of the config server can either pull the new config values from the server and reconfigure themselves or pursue an event driven approach by connecting to a cloud bus.

At  its heart,  Zookeeper   provides    a   hierarchical    namespace   for storing information.    Clients
can insert  new nodes   in  this    hierarchy,  change  them,   or  query   them.   Furthermore,    they    can
add watches to  nodes   to  be  told    when    they    change.

> When should one be used over the other?

In my opinion, Spring Cloud seems a good fit for many cloud-native applications, especially if you're already using spring framework. Also, the repository based approach of config server feels more natural to me and is very flexible, you can easily store generic, application specific and environment based configuration values.  And last but not least, [Spring Cloud Zookeeper](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-zookeeper) is available as part of spring cloud.

Comment: I wonder what are the cons of using Spring Cloud Service in comparison to ZooKeeper | Consul | Archaius ...

Comment: Ideally the spring config server is backed by SVN as well as File System  but Production system are on different n/w as the SVN / GIT hence FileSystem is more ideally suited. Your DevOps can push the svn/git changes to this file system

Comment: @GonenI You're absolutely right. I reworded the comment a bit.