# Spring Cloud Config server Vs ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-config

we have few micro services which interact with each other and we are planning to deploy them in Docker. All are developed in java with Spring Boot. Currently external service configuration are in classpath `application.yml`.

We are looking to move them into centralized config. Want to know which is the best approach Spring Cloud config server approach or Zookeeper.  What is advantage and disadvantage of this 2 approaches.

Does Zookeeper provide dynamic loading of properties upon change? 
Does Spring Cloud config server will be support multiple node/cluster environment setup.

Comment: Try to take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835884/whats-the-difference-between-zookeeper-vs-spring-cloud-config-server It is very well exposed

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Thanks for sharing the info.It's helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between zookeeper vs spring cloud config server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835884/whats-the-difference-between-zookeeper-vs-spring-cloud-config-server)